# Como simular um input ou armazenar uma futura resposta

Tags: python, api, telegram

Estou fazendo um chatbot de Telegram via Python, através de umas aulas que estou fazendo, e no meio do processo me deparei com um problema: não consigo de jeito nenhum armazenar a resposta do cliente em uma variável.

```
class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self):
        token = ''
        self.url_base = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/'

    def Iniciar(self):
        update_id = None
        while True:

            ##obtem novas msgs
            update = self.getMessages(update_id)

            ##define dados como a response da api
            dados = update["result"]
            
            ##se receber dados
            if dados:
                for dado in dados:
                    ##obtem o id da atual conversa
                    update_id = dado['update_id']

                    ## obtem o conteudo da msg
                    mensagem = str(dado["message"]["text"])
                    ## infos basicas
                    sobrenome = str(dado["message"]["from"]["last_name"])
                    nome = str(dado["message"]["from"]["first_name"])

                    ## obtem o chat id
                    chat_id = dado["message"]["from"]["id"]

                    ##verifica se foi a primeira msg
                    primeiraMsg = int(dado["message"]["message_id"]) == 1

                    ##verifica ql msg é
                    msgNumber = int(dado["message"]["message_id"])      

                
                    ## a cada mensagem gera uma resposta 
                    # resposta = self.criar_resposta(saldo, mensagem, primeiraMsg, nome, sobrenome)
                    # self.responder(resposta, chat_id)
            
            if mensagem == '1':
                opcao = msgNumber
                self.responder(f'''Digite o sinal para aposta única no seguinte formato: (exemplo) EURUSD|15:00|M5|PUT|20{os.linesep}Ou seja: ATIVO|HORA|MINUTAGEM|PUT OU CALL|VALOR''', chat_id)
            
            if mensagem == '2':
                opcao = msgNumber
                self.responder(f'''Carregue sua lista formatada''', chat_id)
            
            if opcao == msgNumber + 2:
                apostaResposta = mensagem 
                print(f'''{apostaResposta} essa é a aposta''')

    def getMessages(self, update_id):
      ##link da api pra obter novas atualizações
        link_requisicao = f'{self.url_base}getUpdates?timeout=100'
        ##se tiver algo novo
        if update_id:
          ##seta link requisição pra pegar o ultimo update id
            link_requisicao = f'{link_requisicao}&offset={update_id + 1}'
        resultado = requests.get(link_requisicao)
        return json.loads(resultado.content)

    # Responder
    def responder(self, resposta, chat_id):
        link_requisicao = f'{self.url_base}sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={resposta}'
        requests.get(link_requisicao)

bot = TelegramBot()
bot.Iniciar()
```

O que estou querendo dizer, é que após o cliente selecionar a opção 1, eu gostaria de armazenar a próxima resposta em uma variável. Uma solução pra isso, seria um input, se as respostas fossem via interpretador do python, eu poderia apenas colocar algo como:

```
if mensagem == "1":
   teste = input("INSIRA O ATIVO, SEGUIDO DO VALOR")
   apostar(teste)
```

Teria alguma solução pra isso? Eu consigo simular um input ou armazenar a próxima resposta numa variável?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi armazenar todas as mensagens do usuário em um dicionário, sendo
cada mensagem um objeto.

Mudei um pouco a estrutura do seu codigo, mas é basicamente a mesma coisa

É feito na classe *ExtractData*, ela armazena em um dicionário
os objetos Message e User, que representão os tipos Message e User
do telegram, para cada mensagem recebida serão marcadas com update_id
de cada atualização que ocorrer.

```py
class ExtractData:
    ...

    def getData(self, update_result, lastMsg=False):
        update = self.getCurrentUpdate(update_result)
        if self.previous_update_id != self.current_update_id:
            _message_obj = self.getMessage(update)
            _message_obj.m_from = self.getUser(update)
            self.getInitialTime(_message_obj)
            data = {self.current_update_id: _message_obj}
            del _message_obj

            if lastMsg:
                self.datas = {}     # Guardará somente a última mensagem enviada ao Bot

            self.datas.update(data)
        return
```

Assim, além de poder obter a resposta do usuário vai ser possível
também obter os dados que representão o usuário, a partir do *update_id* das atualizações,
que serão os objetos Message e User.

O metódo *apostaPerguntas* é onde lida com as opções e as repostas do usuário
contidas em `self.extract_data.datas`.

Você pode ver o codigo completo [aqui](https://github.com/ffernandoalves/chatbot_telegram).

### Outros pontos

Pelo o que eu entendi do que você queria fazer,
então a tentativa aqui está correta, mas a lógica não

```py
if opcao == msgNumber + 2:
    ...
```

Você quer verificar se a mensagem enviada pelo o usuário é a resposta
para a opção selecionada, então deve ser verificado se o id da nova mensagem
(message_id) enviada pelo usuário bate com a sequência.

Sendo que message_id = id_da_mensagem_anterior + 2

Então deveria ser:

```py
if msgNumber == opcao + 2:
    ...
```

E nessas verificações

```py
if mensagem == '1':
    ...

if mensagem == '2':
    ...

if opcao == msgNumber + 2:
    ...
```

são necessários dados que podem não ser encontrados.
Pela [documentação](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) da api de bots do Telegram,
alguns dos dados são opcionais dependendo da mensagem.

Como é o caso de

```py
mensagem = str(dado["message"]["text"])
```

Então coloquei uma verificação para esse caso

```py
if "text" not in mensagem.getAttribsList(): # Verifica se a mensagem tem o atributo text
    return
```

Já que nos dados extraidos vai ter o que encontrou, que pode ser o tipo *photo* em vez de *text*.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Você explicou de forma clara e organizou o código de forma simples, consegui compreender a maioria mesmo não tendo muita experiência em Python. Consegui entender a lógica de como você fez, ficou excepcional! Parabéns!

Comment: Sei que é pedir demais, mas surgiu uma nova dúvida. As formas como vão ser tratadas as repostas da opção 1 e 2 são diferentes. Referente ao pós tratamento das opções, eu tenho tudo pronto, o que me deixou em dúvida é como referenciar duas respostas diferentes.

Pensei em testar algo como:

`if mensagem.message_id == self.opcao + 2 and mensagem.text == 1:`
   tratar a resposta 1

`if mensagem.message_id == self.opcao + 2 and mensagem.text == 2:`
   tratar a resposta 1

Comment: @DashaDelas Você pode tentar armazenar os números das opções e os `message_id` em um dicionário. Então, verificar se o usuário está escolhendo uma opção ou enviando a resposta dele. Se ele estiver escolhendo uma opção, preenche o dicionário, ex: `{opc_1:message_id, opc_2:message_id}`, se não, verifica se é uma resposta (como antes) e também se ela corresponde com o tipo esperado (ex lista formatada) para a opção, então faz alguma coisa e depois reset os message_id do dicionário. É melhor fazer uma função para cada caso.

Comment: Entendi o que tu quis dizer, mas as formas de tratar diferentes não são entre uma opção vs reposta, e sim opção número 1 vs opção número 2.